# Taking the quotient of a free monoidal category modulo a relation

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I have recently been advised, in a particular example which is described below, that taking quotients of a category can be complicated, but I don't see where exactly lies the difficulty.

More precisely, I wanted to build a category as such: I take a group-as-category $G$ (i.e. a category with a single object $A$ and invertible morphisms), and form the free strict monoidal category generated by $G$ and a morphism $\mu \colon A^{\otimes 2} \to A$. Then I quotient the category by the relation $\mu \circ k = (k \otimes k) \circ \mu$, for all $k \in G$.

I would thus obtain the free strict monoidal category generated by $G$, $\mu \colon A^{\otimes 2} \to A$, and the above relation, wherein the morphisms are binary forests whose leaves are labelled by elements of $G$.

Is there something wrong with the construction of this category ?

Comment: What are $A$ and $k$? Is $A$ the unique object of the category associated to $G$, and $k \in G$?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: yes, sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: I think there is no difficulty in doing that in this example.

Comment: I think this question can be answered by just writing down precisely the resulting category (objects, morphisms, monoidal structure).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: do you mean with a definition of the form "$\mathcal(C)$ is the category whose objects are... and morphisms are of the form... with the composition given by..." ? I guess this would be possible but I think the generators and relations give more intuition about what is going on in the category. Would it also be correct to define it as the "free monoidal category generated by an object X" with "An object X in a monoidal category is an object $A$ equipped with morphisms $Hom(A,A)=G$ and $\mu: A^{\otimes 2} \to A$ such that $\mu \circ k = (k \otimes k) \circ \mu$" ?

Comment: Yes you could define it that way, but then I don't see any question or problem here.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this answer. I guess one question could be: can one always define the free monoidal category on an object defined by morphisms and relations ?